# Como cambiar el formato en que se ve la hora y fecha thymeleaf y html

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Tengo un input el cual me muestra la fecha y hora de la siguiente manera: "2022-03-23 10:51:07.618"
Necesito que se vea asi "2022-03-23 10:51.
Este es el input

```
<label class="form-label">Fecha Creación</label>
<input th:field="*{creationdate}" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Lo llegue a intentar asi, pero no me funciono:

```
<input th:field="*{#calendars.format(creationdate, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Comment: Hola de entrada le estas indicando dd = dia, MMM = mes , yyyy = año,  si recibes este valor desde una consulta o lo pasas como parametro quizas dandole formato antes de mandar imprimir te dejo material que se relaciona: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php